# Swift - how to conform to two protocols that define a variable with the same name

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to make this work.
I have a class where I adopt two protocols `InputA` and `InputB`.

```
class Example: InputA, InputB {
    
}
```

Both `InputA` and `InputB` protocols define a variable called `output`, but with a different type in each one.

```
protocol InputA {
    
    var output: OutputA? { get set }
    
}

protocol InputB {
    
    var output: OutputB? { get set }
    
}
```

In this way, I cannot conform to both protocols simultaneously.

I tried to achieve this by simply making `OutputA` of type `OutputB`.

```
class Example: InputA, InputB {
    
    var output: OutputA?
    
}

protocol OutputA: OutputB {
    
    func dummyFuncA()
    
}

protocol OutputB {
    
    func dummyFuncB()
    
}
```

But this results in a compilation error that says `Example` does not conform to the `InputB` protocol.

The closest solution I could get was to use an `associatedtype` on `InputB` in addition to the modification made above.

```
protocol InputB {
    
    associatedtype Output
    var output: Output? { get set }
    
}
```

This solution compiles and inside the `Example` class I can access the `OutputA` and `OutputB` functions through the `output` variable. But then, if I try to create a default implementation of some function defined in `InputB`, I can't access the variable `output` as an element of type `OutputB` without casting with `as?`.

If I try to add a type constraint to `associatedtype` like below, class `Example` no longer conforms to `InputB`.

```
protocol InputB {
    
    associatedtype Output: OutputB
    var output: Output? { get set }
    
    func dummyInputB()
    
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this result or am I trying to solve this problem in a dumb way?

Comment: It looks like it's your own protocols so why not just change one of the property names?

Comment: In this case I know that the element that conforms to `OutputA` will always conform to `OutputB`, so I wanted to achieve a level of abstraction where I can access both protocol functions and default implementations through the same variable.

Comment: But it's not the same variable right now, it's two variables with the same name. To me the solution with an associated type looks like the best way forward but it shouldn't be InputA and InputB then only one protocol Input that will replace the other two

Comment: If you only want to access functions of protocol, you need to make protocol A and B be dependant of an associated type, that will be used for output and finally set by the class that implement protocol A and B. Something like : class Example<T:Int> : InputA<T>, InputB<T>